# How to Make two arrays that randomizes numbers between 10 and 30, and 11 and 30 in Java

Tags: java

I have to make two arrays that randomizes numbers between 10 and 30(first array), 11 and 30(second array) in java. i'm supposed to fill the first and second one in numerical order... how? i haven't started yet and i need to be finished soon.

```
int[] a = new int[20];


    int random = (int)(Math.random()*21+10);

    for(int x=0; x<a.length; x++){ 



        System.out.print(random + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(int i=11; i<=30; i++){
        System.out.print(i + " ");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: "I haven't started yet and I need to be finished soon." At first glance, your problem is the "haven't started yet" part.

Comment: I suggest writing some code. 1 Billion times more efficient than writing nothing at all

Comment: plz i suck at programming i have:        int[] i = new int[20];
  int[] x = new int[20];

  for(int y=1; y<=20; y++){

  int randomett=(int)(Math.random() * 30+10);

  }

Comment: @JoarGustafsson that should be in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: You don't store anything in your array. what other problem do you have?

Comment: i cant get it to work, its supposed to create two lines of numbers that are randomized from 11 to 30 and 10 to 30

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> ((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min) to get random with limit

```
int min = 10;
        int max = 30;
        int[] a = new int[20];
        int[] b = new int[20];
        for(int i =0;i<a.length;i++) {
            a[i]= (int) ((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);
        }
        max =  31;
        for(int i =0;i<b.length;i++) {
            b[i]= (int) ((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);
        }
```

this will do